# how can I play opencv frames in a media player, such as MPV?

Tags: python, opencv

I just define the window and play the video in this script, though how would I play the video through a media player instead of opencv? Ideally, I'd do my image processing and be able to view it in mpv in real time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from cv2 import cv2


def main():
    
    def rescale_frame(frame, percent):
        width = int(frame.shape[1] * percent / 100)
        height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent / 100)
        dim = (width, height)
        return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("test.webm")

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        rescaled = rescale_frame(frame, percent=50)
        if ret is True:
            cv2.imshow('Frame', rescaled)

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: use `VideoWriter`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz How would using that function allow me to view the video in real time? Must I need to keep rewriting over the same file in order to see the contents? I'd like to not keep writing as it would add huge delay.

Comment: ah, you want it in realtime! and how do you imagine those other programs accessing the video stream? **everything** will have more latency than `imshow()`. if you see a benefit, please explain it.

Comment: I don't have a benefit in mind beside personal preference, I'd just rather see the video in mpv than the built in player that `imshow()` uses

Comment: you could do a network stream. that involves VideoWriter creating a gstreamer pipeline. plenty of answers explain that already.